# ExcelRenderingExtension: value of cell at row 242,column 3 exceeds the maximum length for a string of 32767 characters

Tags: excel, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, rendering

[image]

How do I solve this issue while exporting SSRS reports to Excel?

Answer (score 2):

The limitation is in Excel, so you really only have two options (both of which truncate your data).

1. Alter you report to use an expression to truncate the data e.g.
   expr = Left(Fields!column.Value, 32767)
2. Alter your query to just pull the first 32767 characters in the
   problematic field SELECT LEFT(FIELD, 32767) as FIELD.
3. If you use stored procs, you could add SET TEXTSIZE 32767 to the
   proc, which will limit the returned data in all varchar(max),
   nvarchar(max), varbinary(max), text, ntext, and image fields to
   32767 characters.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like one of your row value has more than 32767 characters and thus causing the issue while it tries to fit in excel. 
Possible solutions as follows

1. If possible you can split the column. Use LEN() to find the how much space taken my each row of column 3
2. Try using RTRIM/LTRIM to remove any leading and trai ling space for
   the column3
3. Try opening in CSV